# Can an asymptotically efficient estimator be biased?

Tags: self-study, inference, bias, estimators

In "Theory of point estimation" by Lehmann and Casella (1998) there is the following definition:

> [image][image]

It is also said that

> [image]

So terms of the asymptotically normal sequence of estimators can be biased. 
But what about terms of the asymptotically efficient sequence of estimators (i.e. sequence that satisfies both (2.2) and (2.4))? Can they have non-zero bias too?

In other words, I want to know if condition (2.4) adds something new to the statement (i) or not.

**P.S.** Lehmann defines asymptotical unbiasedness as the following (this may seem unusual for some people):

> [image]

Comment: Statement (i) is very strange. Asymtotic unbiasedness is that the bias tends to zero.

Comment: @Viktor see added postscript to my post

Comment: Asymptotically efficient estimators of course can be biased. Example: just about every non-trivial maximum likelihood estimator (assuming the usual regularity conditions). In particular, consider the MLE of $\sigma^2$ for a normal model with unknown mean and variance.

Comment: Again, Definition 2.1 is strange. It would make sense if $H$ were required to be nondegenerate, or the sequence $k_n$ - to be nondecresing.